# Dart: Catch NetworkImage loading error when no valid image url is provided

Tags: flutter, dart

I let user submit image urls in my app which are used to load the images as Network Image afterwards.
Since I only check if the url is valid on submission but not if its a valid image it can happen that  I run into "Exception: Could not instantiate image codec." (e.g. when the url is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)).

How can I catch this exception? I tried using a try / catch statement but this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

fetch/download the image from the url, then construct a image with the bytes

**but**

before doing it when you receive the download response from the url address, check the `Content-type` header is of any type of image for example `image/jpeg` after checking the header, download if its a valid image type, then as i said construct the image from bytes you received